# Can't display values for a user profile in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a simple twitter clone for practice with CodeIgniter and am having difficulty echoing the **first_name** and **last_name** and **date_joined** value from my users table in my user.php view. I just want to show the values for the user that is currently logged in.

I would want the values to echo below the session username in my view. My controller, view, and models are below. Right now I get the following error:

> Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

This is when I just try to echo $user['first_name'], $user['last_name], etc. I had it working before simply echoing out like this but now I can't.
If I do a var_dump of $user I just get the following:

> /app/www/application/views/user.php:5: class stdClass#22 (1) { public $user_id => string(1) "1" }

**Controller: User.php**

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
 function index()
 {
  $this->load->model('login_model');
  $data['user'] = $this->login_model->get_user();
  $data['tweets'] = $this->tweet_model->usertweets();
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('user', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
 }
}
```

**Model: Login_model.php**

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
 function can_login($username, $password)
{
 $this->db->where('username', $username);
 $this->db->where('password', $password);
 $query = $this->db->get('users');

 //SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'

 if($query->num_rows() > 0)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }
}

 function get_user()
 {
  $query = $this->db->get('users');

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $this->db->select('user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_joined');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('username', $username);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->row();
 }
}
```

**Model: Tweet_model.php**

```
class Tweet_model extends CI_Model
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_tweets($tweet_id = false)
{
    if ($tweet_id === false) {
        $this->db->join('users', 'tweets.user_id = users.user_id');
        $query = $this->db->get('tweets');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('tweets', array('tweet_id' => $tweet_id));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function set_tweet()
{
    $tweet = url_title($this->input->post('tweet'), 'dash', true);

    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows())
    {
        $user = $query->row();
        var_dump($user_id);
    }

    $data = array(
      'tweet' => $this->input->post('tweet'),
      'user_id' => $user->user_id
    );

    return $this->db->insert('tweets', $data);
}

function Usertweets() {
  $this->db->flush_cache();

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $this->db->select('user_id');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('username', $username);

  $query = $this->db->get();
  $user = $query->row();

  $this->db->flush_cache();

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('tweets');
  $this->db->where('user_id', $user->user_id);

  return $this->db->get()->result();

}
}
```

**View: user.php**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <h4><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <?php foreach ($tweets as $tweet): ?>
    <div class="user-tweet">
     <h4><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h4>
     <h6><?php echo $tweet->tweet_date; ?></h6>
     <p><?php echo $tweet->tweet; ?></p>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by if $users followed by the value would not work? Do you mean if there was a database error how you would handle it?

Comment: I highly suggest to not redesign the wheel and use `Ion_Auth` for your login/user management needs. It's up-to-date and it's constantly being tested/improved, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because $query->row() returns an object which means you get the values with $user->user_id, not $user['user_id']. If you want to use $user['user_id'], change

```
$user = $query->row();
```

to

```
$user = $query->row_array();
```

Comment: I updated the question, sorry if I am confusing. I just can't get $user['first_name'], $user['last_name'], and $user['date_joined'] echoing in my user view like this. It was working but then it stopped and I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I'll just keep it as an object. However I'm still getting that the property is undefined, for example: **Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$first_name** when I type **echo $user->first_name;**, this is after leaving it as an object.

Comment: Your query may not be returning any rows. Do a var_dump of $query->row() to be sure. Are you sure that $_SESSION['username'] is set correctly? If you set your sessions with CI's session library, it does not use PHP's native session library. You can read more about CI's session library here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html I would also check the number of rows before returning the user information in your view.

Comment: Well I only set the username for the session, the other information (first_name, last_name, & date_joined) I queried based off $username, as you can see in Login_model.php. So doing a var_dump of session returns only the username. And ok so I did var_dump($query->row()); in my user view and got:

Message: Undefined variable: query
Filename: views/user.php
Line Number: 5

Message: Call to a member function row() on null
Filename: /app/www/application/views/user.php
Line Number: 5

Comment: Yes! There I do get the values I need (first_name...,etc.), but how to echo now?

Answer (score 0):

Generally any CI db function call that doesn't contain `array` somwhere in the name returns an object such as `row()` or `result()` with their array counterparts being `row_array()` and `result_array()`.

Arrays are accessed like `$arr['somevalue']` in the view and objects are accessed like `$obj->somevalue`. I can't track down your error because everything looks ok, but I suspect you might be getting no rows and thus foreach fails. *Before foreach it is always a good idea to check if you have anything to print!*

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <?php if (count($tweets) > 0): ?>
    <?php foreach ($tweets as $tweet): ?>
        <div class="user-tweet">
            <h4><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h4>
            <h6><?php echo $tweet->tweet_date; ?></h6>
            <p><?php echo $tweet->tweet; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    No tweets!
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

---

### Code Review

First off, in your `get_users` function remove the first `$query = $this->db->get('users');` as it is unnecessary.

Refactor `can_login` to:

```
function can_login($username, $password) {
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password); 
    return $this->db->count_all_results('users') > 0; // or == 1
}
```

Refactor `set_tweet` following the DRY principle:

```
public function set_tweet() {
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $tweet = url_title($this->input->post('tweet'), 'dash', true);
    $data = array(
        'tweet' => $this->input->post('tweet'),
        'user_id' => $this->login_model->get_user()->user_id
    );
    return $this->db->insert('tweets', $data);
}
```

Should note as a general good practice that you should probably store the `user_id` in a session at login if you are using this that much; it will reduce database strain. **Further, I assume that you don't let any of these actions happen if the user isn't logged in as`$user_id` or any of the user related row fields won't be accessible and will throw a notice if you try and access them.** Redirect the user to login somewhere if (in your case) `$_SESSION['username']` isn't set.

Following the previous refactor you can refactor `Usertweets` to:

```
function Usertweets() {
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    //$this->db->select('*'); * is done for you by default
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->login_model->get_user()->user_id);
    return $this->db->get('tweets')->result(); // object returned
}
```

You might want to consider returning an object to keep everything the same in `get_tweets` as well.